# How to compare negative numbers with positive ones in assembly code?

Tags: assembly, msp430, 16-bit, texas-instruments

I am using a TI MPS430G2553 launchpad and Code Composer Studio v6

I am trying to compare to numbers in an array. I am looping throught the array and at each number I compare that number to the next number in the array. If the next number is less than the current number, they switch positions. Otherwise, nothing happens

I am comparing them using this command:

```
cmp 0(array),1(array)
jl SWITCH
```

The problem is, some of the numbers in the array are negative and they are being treated as their twos complement, for example, when compare 55 and -9, it does not switch them because it is treating -9 as 246 (when i assign it to a register, and use debug mode, the register contains the number 246)

How do i solve this? everything I look up says the solution is to use the `jl` command, but I'm  already doing that.

my memory window shows for this array `10   17  55  -9  22  36  -7
37  8   -77 8`

[Here is the instruction set my professor gave me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5YaT.jpg)

Comment: Subtract (or add) 128 to every number. The byte numbers are -128, ... -1, 0, ... 127 and adding 128 "modulo 256" you'll get the range 0, ...  255,  Or maybe there is a compare-signed or jump-on-minus (jl=less being unsigned).

Comment: When I do this, it still treats the -9 as 246. I add 128 to 246 and get 374, which is still greater than 55+128

Comment: You need to add modulo 256 (i.e. truncating to 8 bits).  The low 8 bits of `128  + 246` gives you 118, which is below (128+55)=183.

Comment: @PeterCordes: How do I add modulo 256? its not in the instruction set.

Comment: Truncating to 8 bit = modulo 256.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing something wrong.  `jl` branches on the signed less-than condition, in MSP430 assembly language, [according to this insn set guide I googled up](https://www.ti.com/sc/docs/products/micro/msp430/userguid/as_5.pdf#page=6):
`JL Label    Jump to Label if (N .XOR. V) = 1`  (where N and V are the Negative and signed-Overflow status bits, so it's identical to x86's JL instruction.  See [Understanding Carry vs. Overflow conditions/flags for signed vs. unsigned.](http://teaching.idallen.com/dat2343/10f/notes/040_overflow.txt)

MSP430 has a `JLO` to branch on the unsigned lower-than condition (if Carry-bit is reset), and you're not using that (which is correct since you want to branch on a signed condition).  It also has `JHS` (Higher or Same, a synonym for JC), but I don't see an equivalent for x86's JA (above: C==0 && Z==0).  Anyway, you don't want unsigned branches anyway.

---

I have a guess at what you're doing wrong:

You say that you see 246 in a register.  So your numbers are definitely only 8-bit.  You're using CMP, not CMP.B, so I think that means you're comparing word-size array elements (unless your assembler magically infers the `.B` from something about `array` being used as an operand).  The insn set ref lists it as `CMP(.B) src,dst`.

Did you zero-extend your numbers to 16-bit instead of sign-extending?  That would explain why CMP isn't setting flags the way you want.

Also, you're only using 0 vs. 1 for array offsets, but that's only one byte and CMP (not CMP.B) uses larger elements than that, so maybe you're doing a 16-bit access that covers two array elements?

(Some of this may be wrong, since I've never used MSP430 before, but it looks like x86 / ARM / M68k / other typical assembly languages.)

Comment: I get the same results whether I use cmp, cmp.b or cmp.w. Switching JL to JLO doesn't work either. How do I know whether I'm zero-extending or sign-extending?

Comment: @MattD: look at memory contents with a debugger.

Comment: That's what I've been doing this whole time. Is something specific I should look for?

Comment: @MattD: yes, whether it's `0 55 0 -9 ...` or whether it's `55 -9 ...`.  It's not clear from the question what's actually in memory.  `cmp.b 0(array), 1(array)` should work if they're packed without any zero-padding, unless there's something tricky about MSP430 that's different from what I expect.  You only ever posted anything in your question about what you saw in registers, not memory.

Answer (score 0):

I changed `cmp 0(ptr),1(ptr)` to `cmp.b 0(ptr),1(ptr)`and that worked